# Can you extend self.included?

Tags: ruby, include, extend

Here's what I want to do, roughly:

```
module Foo

  def self.included base
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

end

module Bar
  extend Foo

  module ClassMethods
    def hi
      return "hello!"
    end
  end
end

class Baz
  include Bar
end

Baz.hi #=> "hello!'
```

but instead I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `hi' for Baz:Class
```

If it's not clear, more generally what I'm trying to do is create one module that contains logic for the `included` callback, which several other modules then extend, and I want them to use the `included` callback from the extended module (but if, e.g., `Bar` extends `Foo`, I'd like `self` to refer to `Bar` in the the closure for `included`, if possible).

Probably that's a bit confusing.

Comment: It is confusing, and confusion is the enemy of transparency.  For the sake of the guy who has to maintain your code, is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I needed to define `included` rather than `self.included` for Bar to get `included` as a class method. The following does what I wanted:

```
module Foo

  def included base
    base.extend self::ClassMethods
  end

end

module Bar
  extend Foo

  module ClassMethods
    def hi
      return "hello!"
    end
  end
end

class Baz
  include Bar
end

Baz.hi #=> "hello!'
```

Answer (score 1):

You never `include Foo` anywhere, therefore the `included` hook is never called. You need to use the `extended` hook, since you `extend Foo`:

```
module Foo
  def self.extended(base)
    base.define_singleton_method(:included) do |base|
      base.extend base::ClassMethods
    end
  end
end

module Bar
  extend Foo

  module ClassMethods; def hi; 'hello!' end end
end

class Baz; include Bar end

Baz.hi #=> 'hello!'
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works, although I found a different one that I prefer.